# Ridge Regression Based on sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Based on Numpy, create data x and label y to train the ridge regression model, and then use another created x and y to predict the regression. The percentage of correct predictions is only 14/64. I don't know where the problem is. Below is my code.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

one_hot = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

x = np.random.rand(64,40) * 2 - 1
y = np.random.randint(0,5,(64,))
y = one_hot.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1,1))
clf = Ridge(alpha=1.0)
readout = clf.fit(x,y)

a = np.random.rand(64,40) * 2 - 1
b = np.random.randint(0,5,(64,))
b = one_hot.fit_transform(b.reshape(-1,1))
y_hat = readout.predict(a)
y_hat = np.argmax(y_hat,axis=1)
target = np.argmax(b,axis=1)
correct = (y_hat == target).sum()

print(correct)     # 14
```

Comment: A regression problem will almost never predict a value thats exactly correct. That's the business of a classification problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am currently using the echo state network to classify the ECG data, and the weight parameters of the echo state network need to be solved by the ridge regression method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For regression to work, one fundamental assumption is that, somehow, **X** should have power to predict **y**.

In your case, both **X** and **y** are randomly generated

```
x = np.random.rand(64,40) * 2 - 1
y = np.random.randint(0,5,(64,))
```

and thus **X** does *NOT* have any predictive power at all. In this scenario, any regression, or fancier machine learning models can produce nothing better than random guess and this is exactly what you get. According to `y = np.random.randint(0,5,(64,))`, **y** is random in the interval `[0, 5)` so for random guess you have a 20% chance to get the right answer and `14/64=0.21875` is just that.